# How to add an icon for tool window in visual studio extension

Tags: window, icons, visual-studio-2019, vs-extensibility, customtool

I created a tool window into my VSIX using

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providetoolwindowattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2019
- https://www.mztools.com/articles/2015/MZ2015004.aspx

I completed creation of my project but unable to upload/show an icon in the menu. How to display an icon in the context menu?

[image]

Comment: This could help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-icons-to-menu-commands?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of bitmap icon and show it on menu command. More details mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-icons-to-menu-commands?view=vs-2019